# How to remove rules from css/app.css with my css file?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In laravel 8/ coreui 3.4 app page news

```
<x-layouts.news>
    <x-slot name="title">{{ trans('News') }}</x-slot>

    ...
    <div class="news-content">{!! \Purifier::clean($news->content_shortly) !!}</div>
    ...

</x-layouts.news>
```

is based on common app layout/css with resources/views/layouts/news.blade.php
template which has 2 css files include :

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/news.css') }}">
...
```

Problem is that when content_shortly of news has

```
<i> and <strong>
```

tags they are not rendered on the form and checking
the page in browser I see that these styles are used from parent html * { : https://prnt.sc/tiYMT3I1NFEo

If there is a way to remove these html * { rules on my page BUT without editing css/app.css,
but only news.css, as these rules are used on other pages of the app ?

**Using unset trying to fix it :**

As I encountered this problem when user fills

```
<i>
```

and

```
<strong>
```

tags in ckeditor5

I added at top of my scss

```
strong {
    font-weight: unset;
}

i {
    font-weight: unset;
}
```

but that does not work anyway and in browser I see : https://prnt.sc/tTObhLlAvgUR

I tried to add style :

```
html * {
    font-weight: unset !important;
    text-decoration: unset !important;
    font-style:  unset !important;
}

* {
    font-weight: unset !important;
    text-decoration: unset !important;
    font-style:  unset !important;
}
```

But that also did not help -  and  tags are not rendered at all...

Comment: I guess, you can use `!important` in your css class, instead of removing. :)

Comment: Increase the specificity of the rules in `news.css`.

Comment: @Mitesh Rathod,  How can I set !important into <i>, <strong> tags which are set by rtf editor ?

Comment: @Simon Weber, Please explain how can I Increase the specificity of the rules ?

Comment: You would have to share your code for that. In the meantime [have a read about it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to keep the bolt in `<strong>` and italics in `<i>`, that is, the initial values for these elements. I think you can use the [**revert**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert) value:

```css
html * {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* instead of html, you can specify a content wrapper  */
html i {
  font-style: revert;
}

html strong {
  font-weight: revert;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit <strong>amet</strong>, consectetur <i>adipisicing</i> elit. Commodi, vel.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `!important` flag in your CSS file.

```css
.news-content,
.news-content > p {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
```

It will override the your parent CSS.

Comment: No I would like to leave news-content > p as it it now, but as content_shortly of a news is edited in rtf editor by user and <i>, <strong> tags are added there

Comment: you want to remove `<i>` and `<strong>` tags?

Comment: No, they are not visible(not rendered). I show it in my printscreen

Answer (score 0):

use unset for every rule that you want to remove:

```css
* {
    font-weight: unset;
  }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the first case, when the property is an inherited property, and like the initial keyword in the second case, when the property is a non-inherited property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Very interesting point, but I tryed and failed to check it.m Please look at Using unset trying to fix it block